# Why doesn't Git daemon start in the background?

Tags: git

Just as in the title, why doesn't `git daemon` start the service in the background, since it's a "daemon", being a background process? I know that I can start it in the background using `git daemon &`, but I'm just wondering about the philosophical reason for this decision.

Comment: You're likely looking for the `--detach` or `--inetd` options, which is fairly standard daemon options.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Any reason why these aren't the default options?

Comment: It is likely the least damaging of the options if you forget to include it at the wrong time.  Consistency maybe too - everything else in git runs from a shell by default, why have just one that doesn't? Beyond that, one starts needing to read the source to see if there are comments around that code block or the original repository to get hints of the intent... or ask Linus directly.

Comment: Thanks for that, your explanation makes sense and I was just looking for some rational behind the decision. Would you mind upgrading your comments to an answer, and I could select it as the correct one? Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue but does not provide enough information to make the question answerable elsewhere.

Comment: Running with `&` won't work, because such process will still receive hangups from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is likely consistency.  All of the other git subcommands are intended to be invoked from the shell.  To have one subcommand work differently may surprise some people.  Beyond this, its just a guess that *may* be found somewhere in the depths of the the [git@vger.kernel.org](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com) mailing list, the comments on the code, the commits for the revisions, or the mind if Linus (in likely order of accessibility).

There are options for the `git daemon` subcommand that make it work better than appending an `&` after the command.  From the [kernel.org documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) (note the examples of the starting options at the end):

> **`--inetd`**
>   Have the server run as an inetd service. Implies --syslog. Incompatible with --detach, --port, --listen, --user and --group options.
>
> **`--detach`** Detach from the shell. Implies --syslog.

One might also want to look at the git-daemon tags on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/git-daemon) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-daemon) for related setup help.